# How to set up Exchange ActiveSync + iPhone?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003, iphone, activesync

If you inherited an already configured server which is running Exchange Server 2003: where would you locate the settings on the server that you would need to configure Exchange on iPhone 2.0?

Comment: What you are asking, I think, is how to install and setup Exchange (I assume 2003 or 2007) to also serve mobile devices. But since you have no idea at all, you can't even word it. iPhone 2.0 comes with Exchange ActiveSynch, which allows the device to connect to a properly configured Exchange, like a Windows Mobile device would, for example (it works even better, actually). Your question title is wrong, and the question itself needs serious editing.

Comment: I've edited my original question, and a couple comments. David was responding to a very differently worded question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice video podcast which explains in detail what steps you have to follow on your server and the iPhone in order to allow Exchange access.

[**IT Idiots - Episode 69: Exchange, ActiveSync and the iPhone**](http://www.techpodcasts.com/itidiots/80900/episode-69-exchange-activesync-and-the-iphone/)

> The iPhone is out and it now has a
>   place in the corporate world. In this
>   episode we discuss the Exchange
>   ActiveSync features such as the new
>   autodiscover, remote wipe and
>   enforceable security policies and then
>   take you step by step through the
>   configuration of Exchange 2007, DNS
>   and the iPhone itself. Oh yeah and
>   this feature is provided out of the
>   box, no BlackBerry licenses required!

Then, read Apple's PDF document which also explains the details on how to configure your Exchange server for the iPhone:

[**iPhone and Microsoft Exchange Server (PDF)**](http://images.apple.com/iphone/enterprise/docs/iPhone_MS_Exchange.pdf)

> iPhone 2.0 software communicates
>   directly with your Microsoft Exchange
>   Server via Microsoft Exchange
>   ActiveSync, giving users push email,
>   contacts, and calendar. Exchange
>   ActiveSync maintains a connection
>   between Exchange Server and iPhone so
>   when a new email message or meeting
>   invitation arrives, iPhone is
>   instantly updated.
>
> If your company currently supports
>   Exchange ActiveSync on Exchange Server
>   2003 or 2007, you already have the
>   necessary services in place to support
>   iPhone 2.0 software—no additional
>   configuration is required. If you have
>   Exchange Server but your company is
>   new to Exchange ActiveSync, review the
>   following steps to enable Exchange
>   ActiveSync.

Answer (score 4):

To setup an Exchange account on iPhone, all you need to know is:

- Server name (FQDN)
- Domain\Username
- Password

The iPhone (or any other ActiveSynch capable device) doesn't care about anything else.

Comment: See my comment to your question. If you are asking how to configure Exchange (please state version) to allow mobile device to connect to it, then iPhone is irrelevant, it will apply to all devices capable of ActiveSynch. Why do you keep referring to Windows 2003, by the way? If you sincerely want to learn, you need to hit some serious literature (start from computer basics, move to Windows OS, and then tackle Exchange, if that is what you are interested at).

Comment: I've edited my original question, and a couple comments. David was responding to a very differently worded question.

Answer (score 2):

Exchange ActiveSync is on by default in Exchange 2003 and later, although there may be things that you need to set up to get EAS access through your firewall.

Apple's so-called [Enterprise Integration](http://www.apple.com/iphone/enterprise/integration.html) web page has two docs that may help: this one covers the s[etup steps required for Exchange 2003](http://images.apple.com/iphone/enterprise/docs/iPhone_MS_Exchange.pdf), and [this one](http://images.apple.com/iphone/enterprise/docs/How_To_Setup_Guide.pdf) covers what the iPhone user has to do.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to be running Exchange ActiveSync somewhere to allow the iPhone to connect to exchange, much in the same way that the RIM software integrates with Blackberry.  Installing the Client Access server role on your exchange server effectively enables ActiveSync.

You can read more about it on [Microsoft's site](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998357.aspx).

Once that is up and running, David's answer is effectively correct.  You point the device at the server, and use a username and password which exists, and has a mailbox on, your domain.

This will allow the iPhone to sync email, calendars, contacts, etc.

A walkthrough of the iPhone side of things can be found [here](http://www.theiphoneblog.com/2008/07/13/walkthrough-exchange-activesync-on-your-iphone-20/).

Comment: the OP was asking about Exchange 2003, which doesn't have the CAS role.

Answer (score 0):

You really should purchase an SSL certificate for your Exchange server so to say it's licensee free is a tidge untrue.

Cheers, Rob.

Comment: A SSL Certificate is not a licence.